# UIFileSharingEnabled use folders

Tags: iphone, ios, file-sharing

I want to allow users add files to the application document folder, so I used the iTunes file sharing. The problem is they can only add single files with a flat structure. I want to drag and drop whole folder (even with sub folders) and keep the structure.

Questions I have:

1. is it possible with iTunes file sharing?
2. if not, is there an open source project that helps me with writing a pc side app that talks to the iPhone side app and pushes the files into it?

Answer (score 1):

1. No you can't add Folder's/sub folders, iTunes will show just the files in the documents root. I think the only way to do that is to add it as zip file and you extract it in your app.
2. Maybe [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) will help you.

Comment: Thanks, CocoaHTTPServer was wonderful. however, when I compile the webdav sample in iPhone, everything works fine in emulator, but on the actual device, it seems to stop "accepting" the data after 16MB of transfer. might be a memory issue, do you happen to know anything about it?